# How can I delete U+200B (Zero-width space) using sed

Tags: regex, unicode, sed

I have a very large file that has zero-width spaces scattered throughout.  It takes too long to open and edit using `vi` so I'd like to delete all instances of the character using `sed`.  The problem is, I can't figure out how to match the character!  I've tried using `\u200B`, `\x{200b}`.  Any ideas?

I'm running CentOS 5 if that helps at all.

Comment: Does your copy of sed support the Unicode encoding that the file is encoded with?  If not there is probably no good way to do it properly with sed, and you'd better use a python script or something like that...

Comment: @JanC - indeed, I've gone with Python.  The file is encoded with utf8, seems standard enough that anything should be able to process it.  I've added my python script below, in case its useful to anyone.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This seems to work for me:

```
sed 's/\xe2\x80\x8b//g' inputfile
```

Demonstration:

```
$ /usr/bin/printf 'X\u200bY\u200bZ' | hexdump -C
00000000  58 e2 80 8b 59 e2 80 8b  5a                       |X...Y...Z|
$ /usr/bin/printf 'X\u200bY\u200bZ' | sed 's/\xe2\x80\x8b//g' | hexdump -C
00000000  58 59 5a                                          |XYZ|
```

**Edit:**

Based partially on Gilles' answer:

```
tr -d $(/usr/bin/printf "\u200b") < inputfile
```

Comment: Perfect - this is exactly what I was looking for.  In fact, I noticed that same set of characters (`\xe2\x80\x8b`) when looking at some sample strings in Python.  Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

GNU sed's behavior with UTF-8 doesn't seem to be very well-defined. Experimentally, you can make it replace the bytes of the UTF-8 representation:

```
<old sed 's/\xe2\x80\e8b//g' >new
```

Alternatively, you can type the character into your shell and use any of the standard commands in a UTF-8 locale:

```
<old tr -d '​' >new
<old sed 's/​//g' >new
```

In zsh, you can also enter the character through an escape sequence:

```
<old tr -d $'\u200B' >new
```

Comment: As of Bash 4.2, Unicode sequences are supported by `echo -e`, `printf` format strings and ANSI quoted strings (e.g. `echo -e '\u1E4F'`, `printf '\u01DD %s\n' 'X'`, `mkdir $'\u0250`)

Answer (score 0):

Well, unless anyone has any ideas for how to get `sed` to do this (which I'm still interested in, by the way) its Python to the rescue...

```
import sys, re
pattern = re.compile(u"\u200b")
f = open(sys.stdin, "rb")
for line in f:
    a = pattern.sub("", line.decode("utf8"))
    print a.encode("utf8"),
f.close()
```

Comment: If you're going to reach for the big guns, how about the much simpler `perl -C -pe 's/\x{200B}//g'`?

Comment: +1 to the Gilles which also works on Mac OSX. `perl -C -pi.bak -e 's/\x{200B}//g' yourfile` results in yourfile fixed and a backup in yourfile.bak